# Check if NSURL is an Asset

Tags: ios, assets

I have a NSURL class member wich can point to a **local file**, to a **URL** or to an **Asset**. I've found out that I have to use the Asset Library to load an Asset instead of:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:nsurl];
```

So my Question is: **How can I check if my NSURL object points to an Asset?**

I've tried the search, but I've only how to check if it's a local file :(

PS: My App has to be iOS4 compatible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the URL is well-formed, it is an Assets Library URL iff `[[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"assets-library"]`.